# Шифр на базе М-последовательности

Tags: c++, алгоритм, криптография, шифрование

Есть задание:

1. Реализовать генератор М-последовательности заданной длинны.
2. Построить шифратор-дешифратор на основе полученного генератора М-последовательности.

Генератор псевдослучайных чисел я сделал, но понять не могу, как с его помощью шифровать можно.
Можете подсказать, ибо уже несколько часов ломаю голову.

Не обязательно код, просто объяснение алгоритма будет отлично

Comment: А как этот негератор выглядит? Он принимает что то на входе? Типа какое то число, которое можно как ключ использовать? Например, если передавать одно и то же число на вход генератору, будет ли он генерировать одну и ту же последовательность?

Comment: Ряд псевдослучайных чисел == ряд байт == ключ симметричного шифрования. Как вариант.

Comment: Да хоть обычный шифр, основанный на сдвиге. Ключом является исходное значение ("зерно") генератора. Шифрование - циклический сдвиг по алфавиту на очередное значение, возвращенное генератором. Дешифровка - сдвиг в обратную сторону...

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое, думаю так и есть

Answer (score 2):

Я не буду писать какой-то конкретный алгоритм, ибо потенциальных алгоритмов тьма и маленькая тележка.

Вашу задачу можно решать двумя разными путями: гаммирование и выведение ключей для существующего блочного шифра. В обоих случаях предполагается, что ваша М-последовательность генерируется из какого-то начального значения, которое будет служить ключом для шифра.

## Гаммирование

[Гаммирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) или XOR шифр, придуман ажно самим Шенноном. Реализация проста. Сначала по ключу генерируете псевдослучайную последовательность `N` (noise) длиной `L` байтов. Байты шифртекста `C[i]` получаются из байтов открытого теста `P[i]` сложением по модулю два с соответствующим байтом шума:

```
C[i] = P[i] XOR N[i mod L]
```

Для расшифровки получатель шифртекста, зная ключ, генерирует ту же самую последовательность `N` и расшифровывает, ксоря байты шифртекста и шума:

```
P[i] = C[i] XOR N[i mod L]
```

## Генерация раундовых ключей

Все современные блочные шифры организованы в раунды. Внутри одного шифра раунды устроены практически одинаково - перемешивание битов и подмешивание битов ключа. Для стойкости на для каждого раунда из исходного ключа генерируется раундовый ключ. К примеру, в AES раундовые ключи генерируются [вот так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9), а в DES - [вот так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES#%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000044-QINU%60%22%27%7F).

Для вашего задания вы могли бы взять открытую реализацию AES или DES и заменить в ней алгоритм генерации раундового ключа. Если длина раундового ключа `R` байтов, то ключ `K[i]` для i-того раунда будет состоять из байтов `N[i*R], N[i*R+1], ..., N[i*R+(R-1)]`

Вот, как-то так.